# Handling different startDestination in android single activity Navigation graph

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I want to implement a single activity project.
After showing splash i want to navigate to HomeFragment or LoginFragment based on user's login condition. In the MainActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (userLoggedIn()) {
        navigateToHomeScreen()
    } else {
        navigateToLoginScreen()
    }
}
```

The question is how should i set the navigation xml? Which one of the fragments should be the startDestionation. What's the best approach for a smooth splash/login( sign-in/sign-up/forget-pass)/ home flow.

Comment: You would have to make two navigation graphs and use it as nested nav graph, 
One for your sign up , one when user logs in.

Comment: Yes, but which fragment should be the startDestination? Previously we used SplashActivity to handle this. but now that we don't have a starting fragment i dont know where to start.

Comment: Did you read the [guide specifically on how you should handle login with the Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login)?

Comment: Yeah read the guide ianhanniballake posted, it's explicitly about this - but just to make the point, the *start destination* is always present in your backstack for the nav graph. If you back out of the graph, the *start destination* is always the last fragment you see. So if the user backs out of your app, which should be the last screen they pass through? The splash screen? (No, that would look weird and bounce you forward to the next screen.) The login screen? Not great if they're already logged in. Really you want it to be the *home screen*, right? And that has to send you to the others